# Geolocation issues

Tags: android, geocoding

Please help me to solve this. Whenever I start my app , the code crashes. I am a beginner to Android. My code:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.myapplication">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

This is my xml code activity_main.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:id="@+id/tv1"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

This is my java code:

```
    package com.example.myapplication;

import android.content.Context;
import android.location.Criteria;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    LocationManager mLocationManager;
    TextView tv;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        tv=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv1);

        mLocationManager=(LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        Criteria criteria=new Criteria();

        criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);

        criteria.setPowerRequirement(Criteria.POWER_LOW);

        String locationprovider=mLocationManager.getBestProvider(criteria,true);

        Location mLocation=mLocationManager.getLastKnownLocation(locationprovider);

        tv.setText("LAST LOCATION LAT:"+mLocation.getLatitude()+"long:"+mLocation.getLongitude());

    }
}
```

Whenever i run this code, the app crashes automatically..I dont know why it happens.
Thanks in advance, please say what i should change and what is the reason.

Comment: `I dont know why it happens` How can WE figure it out, if you do not post your logcat?

Comment: As mentioned above you should put your LogCat in the question. That being said I can see that you are asking for location data without seeking permissions at runtime

Comment: Try this: https://www.journaldev.com/10409/android-runtime-permissions-example

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to make a location request without getting the users permission.

You need to ask the user to explicitly accept location permissions at runtime. You can do that by adding the below code to your `MainActivity`.

Once set up you just need to call `checkLocationPermission();` in your `onCreate` method.

This is an untested example and it's not completely thorough but it should help you along.

[Here](https://www.journaldev.com/10409/android-runtime-permissions-example) is a more in depth example.

```
public static final int LOCATION_PERMISSIONS_CODE = 99;

public boolean checkLocationPermission() {
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        // Should we show permission rationale
        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) {

            AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Request Location");
            alertDialogBuilder.setMessage("Access to Location data required");
            alertDialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                            //carry out permisison request on button tap
                            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, LOCATION_PERMISSIONS_CODE);
                        }
                    });
            alertDialogBuilder.create();
            alertDialogBuilder.show();

        } else {
            // here we can go ahead and carry out permission request
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, LOCATION_PERMISSIONS_CODE);
        }
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case LOCATION_PERMISSIONS_CODE: {
            // check if request has the same code as LOCATION_PERMISSIONS_CODE and has been granted
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                // permission was granted
                if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    //Request location updates:
                }

            } else {
                // permission denied
            }
            return;
        }

    }
}
```